# Proving travel history from years ago on an expired passport

Tags: passports, kenya

I'm trying to prove that I was a tourist in Kenya on two six month tourist visas in 2006/7, but don't have any records for it. The visa stamps would be in an old passport that I no longer have, and the email address I used for the flights is closed.

Any ideas on how I can prove I was there? I need this so I can request a police check for immigration purposes to Canada.

Thank you

Comment: A lesson to be learned, don't throwaway expired passports.  You can try contacting the airline, they maybe able to research your old flights for a fee.  You can try contacting the Kenyan government, they maybe be able to research your old immigration records for a fee.  But otherwise there is no other source of records.

Comment: Old frequent flyer account statements maybe, if the website goes back that far and that's acceptable proof to the authorities.

Comment: @Tom that's assuming that the OP's government doesn't withdraw expired passports. That's why I make copies of my passports when I renew my passports.

Comment: @dda - does France not return expired passports when you renew?

Comment: You may keep a cancelled passport ONLY if you have a current visa in it (which is why I try to get a Chinese visa before renewal). Korea is the same, and plenty of countries too. This is derived from the principle that a passport is not yours, but the government's, and when you're done with it, the gubmint takes it back.

Comment: @dda - all the "gubmits" I have dealt with give them back, so my advice to keep expired passports is still valid, even if your "gubmit" doesn't let you.  The US asks to see all old passports when you apply for a visa, so quite a few countries do give back expired passports elsewise they wouldn't bother asking.